# Finding Check Boxes value using Javascript inside of Jira

Tags: javascript, jira

I am trying to get the ID of an element within my Jira create bug page. I have the element ID but whenever I try and use it, it returns null and the script stops working. Right now, I am setting the control to disappear depending on what priority is being set. I have gotten this to work with text boxes, but not a check box, can someone please help me. Here is my code below.

```
console.log("starting script");
priority = document.getElementById('priority');
if (priority) {
  console.log(priority.value);
  target = document.getElementById('customfield_10411');
  console.log(target.value);
  // Hide the target field if priority isn't critical
  if (priority.value != 2) 
    target.style.display='none';

  priority.onchange=function() {
      if (this.value == 2) {             
      } 
      else {
         target.style.display='none';
      }
  }
}
```

I feel like one of the issues may be that this is a custom field I created, and while it is only has one check box, it is a multi-checkbox field

Comment: Without seeing the HTML in question, it's hard to say anything useful.

Comment: Do you run this code *after* the elements are created?

Comment: This code is ran whenever the "create issue" window is opened and will run whenever priority is changed. I have tested this using other custom fields, such as a text box, and it worked as expected. The ElementID should be correct because I used the same method to find it as I did the text box

Comment: try something like this: JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function(e, context, reason) {
        ////
    });

Comment: I am not sure how this works, could you give me an example? For instance, a check box being checked, and hiding something in response?

Comment: Try to wrap your code in JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function(e, context, reason) { //// your code here });